# Receipt not allowing letters

Tags: c#

I'm trying to make it so my receipt is able to enter both letters and numbers.

```
        decimal counter;
        decimal item;
        decimal price;
        decimal subtotal;
        decimal tax;
        decimal total;
        decimal quantity;

        subtotal = 0;
        counter = 0;


        while (counter <= 10)
        {
            Console.Write("Item{0}", counter + 1);
            Console.Write("        \tEnter item: ");
            item = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
            if (item == 0)
                break;
            Console.Write("        Enter price: ");
            price = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());


            counter = counter + 1;

            Console.Write("        Enter quantity: ");
            quantity = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            subtotal += price * quantity;
        }
        Console.WriteLine("-------------------");
        Console.WriteLine("\nNumber of Items:{0}", counter);
        Console.WriteLine("Subtotal is {0}", subtotal);
        tax = subtotal * 0.065M;
        Console.WriteLine("Tax is {0}", tax);
        total = tax + subtotal;
        Console.WriteLine("Total is {0}", total);
        Console.WriteLine("Thanks for shopping! Please come again.");
        Console.Read();
```

For example, lets say I'm buying an apple and an I enter "apple" where it says "Enter item" and then enter the quanity and price. Then I decide I want to end it so I enter 0 to break the code. I'm capable of entering numbers just fine, but when I enter a letter it won't work.

Comment: Why item in `decimal` when you are entering the string as 'apple'?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want enter something like `"apple"` this code won't work:

```
Console.Write("        \tEnter item: ");
item = Convert.ToDecimal(Console.ReadLine());
if (item == 0)
    break;
```

Here you try to parse some symbols (not digits) to `decimal` - as a result you should get exception.

Change your code to:

```
Console.Write("        \tEnter item: ");
item = Console.ReadLine();
if (item == "0")
    break;
```

Also, change type of `item`:

```
string item;  //previously decimal item;
```